# BLOB Snapshot Metadata

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am setting metadata on each BLOB creation at storage. I am creating snapshot of BLOB also at time of creation. When I got o View Snapshot, I am unable to see metadata for BLOB in particular snapshot. On BLOB properties I can see metadata in properties. How I can see different metadata set at time of BLOB creation in portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the portal shows metadata only for base blob and not snapshots ,If you have azure storage explorer installed you would be able to see the metadata in snapshots if the metadata was set at the time of blob creation.
You can set metadata at the time of blob creation additionally metadata can also be set while creating snapshots(**setting metadata on blob snapshot is not allowed from portal or explorer but can be done through SDK**).
If while creating a snapshot metadata is not provided then base blob's metadata is copied over.

Comment: How I can set metadata at the time of creating snapshot using .net